# Setting a password for a shared file

Tags: rest, onedrive

I would like to share a file and protect it by a password thanks to the API REST as it is possible from the OneDrive user interface.

Thanks to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/shared?view=odsp-graph-online), I have been able to see it is possible by making these requests:
PUT /me/drive/items/{item-id}/content

```
PATCH /me/drive/items/{item-id}
Content-type: application/json
{
    "shared": {
        "owner": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.identitySet" },
        "scope": "anonymous",
        "sharedBy": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.identitySet" },
        "sharedDateTime": "datetime"
        },
}
```

I'm not able to find any password property in the documentation.

Is it a missing in the documentation or this property is not available?

Answer (score 0):

Its Limitation.

OneDrive's REST API did not support directly setting a password for a shared link through the API calls you mentioned.

OneDrive's user interface does allow for setting a password on shared links, but this feature may not be exposed through their API.

The API calls you're referring to – PUT /me/drive/items/{item-id}/content and PATCH /me/drive/items/{item-id} – are used for updating the content of an item and modifying the properties of a driveItem, respectively. However, these do not include functionality for setting a password on a shared link.